# Given a list of recipes a list of owned ingredients, which algorithm is best to determine "Which ingredient could I add to access the most recipes?"

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph-theory, coding-efficiency

I hope the long title does a decent job of explaining the question. This feels like a nominal question so I suspect there is a known algorithm for this, or maybe it maps to NP.

Given a cookbook in the form of

```
cookbook = {
    recipe1: [ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient35],
    recipe2: [ingredient1, ingredient8, ingredient12], 
    recipe3: [ingredient10, ingredient22, ingredient35],
    ...
}
```

And a list of ingredients in the form

```
ingredients = {
    ingredient1: true, //owned
    ingredient2: false, //unowned
    ingredient3: true,
    ...
}
```

Which algorithm would efficiently answer "Which ingredient can you add to complete the most recipes?"

Assume

- There are a large number of recipes & ingredients
- A given recipe will not have more than 10 ingredients
- You can transform/manipulate the data however you see fit
- The grading criteria is how efficient can you make an algorithm which can answer "Which ingredient should I add to make the most recipes, given the ingredient's I already own"
- A person could add/remove ingredients at random, and must be able to answer the "Which ingredient?" question efficiently
- Space complexity can be ignored for now
- Then intent is design a data structure + algorithm, however computationally complex that might be, which allows for rapid queries. The 'grading' is how fast those future queries are

Comment: I suspect converting the ingredient lists to bitmaps would work well. Applying bit-wise math to those is fast and produces answers that are easy to filter relative to the kinds of queries you have.

Comment: Minor nit-pick: it seems like you're asking for a dynamic data structure to respond to various queries, rather than a single algorithm. Is that an accurate rephrasing? Also, do you know the relative number of 'add/remove ingredients' queries to 'best ingredient' queries? Any data structure will have a tradeoff between optimizing those two.

Comment: Yes, that is a better rephrasing, I'll modify the question. The intent is to format the data (even if this step is expensive) in such a way that future calls are as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo code

```
bestIngredient = 0
bestCount = 0
Loop I  over owned ingredients
   count = 0
   Loop R over recipes
       If I completes R
          increment count
   if count > bestCount
      bestCount = count
      bestIngredient = I
```

When an ingredient I is added:

```
Loop R over recipies
    If R needs I 
    Add I to R
```

Comment: I think you meant loop over not owned ingredients

Comment: This is a fine solution except it is quite slow. O(unownedIngrediants * recipes) ~ O(n^2)
Maybe this is the best that exists, but I was hoping for something faster

Answer (score 1):

Create a trie from the recipes. For each query, recurse on subsequences of the query and one allowed wildcard, walking the trie. (Both recipes and query should sort ingredients in the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

```
score = empty hashmap
for each R in recipes
  missing = empty list
  for each I in R
    if ingredients[i] = false
      missing += I
  if size(missing) = 1
    I = missing[0]
    score[I]++
result = choose key I in score with maximum value
```